# Outputing utf8 CSV using Golang

Tags: csv, go

I am rewriting a form of CSV to canonical CSV with Golang:

```
func main() {
    txtfile, err := os.Open("data.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Couldn't open the csv file", err)
    }

    r := csv.NewReader(txtfile)
    r.Comma = ':'

    records, err := r.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    w := csv.NewWriter(os.Stdout)

    for _, record := range records {
        if err := w.Write(record); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln("error writing record to csv:", err)
        }
    }

    // Write any buffered data to the underlying writer (standard output).
    w.Flush()

    if err := w.Error(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

data.txt looks like:

```
$ cat data.txt
2006-11-02:S� Paulo:-23.561:-46.645
$ base64 < data.txt
MjAwNi0xMS0wMjpT428gUGF1bG86LTIzLjU2MTotNDYuNjQ1Cg==
$ md5sum data.txt
60d7f1fc0eb7176896bff9e9eca2aec6  data.txt
$ file data.txt
data.txt: ISO-8859 text
```

I was assuming Go could read this and output utf8, but the resulting saved output:

```
file data.csv
data.csv: ISO-8859 text
```

When I use the file with sqlite-utils, it bombs out with:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 12: invalid continuation byte
```

So what should be my approach to ensure the output CSV is utf8 in Golang?

Comment: Did you notice the � in position 12 in the output of `cat data.txt`? What character should that be?

Comment: How do I convert my data.txt to be proper Unicode then to avoid the garbage in? http://maps.natalian.org/data.txt